# Recommendations for managing dedicated server DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, dedicated-server

I've rented a dedicated server for several years with a number of domains. I've got a coding background so am comfortable with that side of the tech, but I hate that I still don't truly understand DNS settings.

Example: My provider (hostgator) just told me that my parent nameservers are not correctly configured as there is no A record for my primary nameserver.

What book/link/tutorial should I read to go from kind of understanding that comment to really understanding it & knowing exactly what I need to do to fix it rather than trial & error which is what I usually do.

Thanks

BTW I'm using a WHM/cpanel linux setup at hostgator but am eager to learn the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have a forward lookup (A record) specified for your nameserver. (IE. ns1.example.com)

O'Reilly's [DNS and BIND](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100575) book is quite good.  The [DNS-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO.html) has some great technical details.  [Searching the Internet](http://www.google.com/) will also uncover substantial details regarding DNS, as it is an old protocol.

[DNS for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/)  is a book that is published on the Internet, which I love to use for reference.

Specific to Cpanel, there is [various documentation](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/) regarding DNS on their Web site.

Finally, reading and knowing the [RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Internet_standards) is a great way to support your knowledge with the foundation of any Internet protocol.

Comment: What a terrific answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks. Thanks also to the others who responded. I also appreciate that both books you mention are available online/ebook so I can get cracking right away. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Also note http://www.checkdns.net

You can fast-check your dns setup there.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at some of the tutorials on the easydns and dnsmadeasy websites, they probably show the essentials in an easy to digest format.